# xCode - Team not selectable in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm creating an app for someone who, to my advice, joined the Apple Developer Program himself. He added me as developer in iTunes connect so that I could upload builds, but once I'm inside of xCode his team doesn't show up in the accounts section.

He created iOs distribution and development certificates as well as provision profiles but the team still won't show up.

My question is: which certificates/profiles does he (or me?..) have to set up to allow me to upload to his account?

Notice: (Yes, I have tried deleting and re-adding the account in xCode)

Comment: iTunesConnect and developer centre are different accounts. You should login to developer.apple.com to check the certificates & profiles.

Comment: @srvv I can't, the certificates & profiles are only visible and changable to the leader of a team, which is not me.

Comment: Then you should ask him to add you from developer centre and you will need distribution certificate he created.

Comment: @srvv that's the thing I asked; where should he add me, and which distribution certificate do I need?

Comment: The person who created distribution certificate can export it from his keychain. When he will login to developers.apple.com he should be able to add another person to the team.

Comment: @srvv Can a person add members to his team when he has an individual entity type, or does he has to have an organization?

Comment: I don't think that's possible for an individual account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115007/discussion-between-srvv-and-merijn-den-houting).